# HttpClient cannot ignore or bypass self signed certificate error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, httpclient

I have tried to send a POST data to a server but i received an error , “net::ERR_CERT_INVALID”. The code as shown below is what I tried to bypass the error but it’s still fail. Please help advice. Thank you.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

createData(data): Promise<any> {
    let post_message = data;
    let header_node = {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      rejectUnauthorized: 'false',
    }
    // this.oauth_header.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + access_token;
    const url_params = new HttpParams()
      .set('rejectUnauthorized', 'false')
      .set('requestCert', 'false')
      .set('insecure', 'true')

    return this.http.post('https://ip/createdata', post_message, {
      headers: header_node,

    }).toPromise();
```

Comment: Hi @CBV, could you resolve this error in angular?

Answer (score 4):

**Try passing headers as `HttpHeaders` to `POST` method.**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

createData(data): Promise<any> {

    let post_message = data;
    let header_node = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders(
            { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
            { 'rejectUnauthorized': 'false' })
        };

    return this.http.post('https://ip/createdata', post_message, header_node).toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while since this post was posted, nevertheless, I ran into a similar problem with a keycloak dev server (self-signed cert = invalid), I was building an angular 13+ app to interact with it.
As I asume you were receiving this error from browser, let me say that it's not kind of HttpClient or Angular problem, but the browser blocking the process, then for future cases, **here** is the **"solution/bypass":**

Go to the browser, type your server URL/IP (the invalid certificate one), and then, when invalid cert browser alert prompts out, allow access for the browser to navigate there. I've granted access by the image below but also in privacy&security settings (chrome tested)
[Browser screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ2vT.png)

For me it worked, hope it helps for people like me few years later trying to solve the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that try to bypass the self signed certificate verification in your angular test, I've done it with

=> `window._resourceLoader._strictSSL = false;`

in `before` or anywhere else before your calls.

For more info `HttpClient` from angular use `createClient` in `xhr-utils.js` from `jsdom` that use the `XMLHttpRequestImpl` class in test and in the class we have

```
class XMLHttpRequestImpl extends XMLHttpRequestEventTargetImpl {
    [...]
    this.flag = {
      [...]
      strictSSL: window._resourceLoader._strictSSL,
      [...]
    };
    [...]
}
```

`strictSSL` to false is the key to disabled the verification as is it used
by `createClient` in `xhr-utils.js` from `jsdom` to disabled ssl verifications.