# Angular 13 how to bypass net::ERR_CERT_INVALID

Tags: angular, boot, sprint

```
 private baseUrl = 'https://diallosuer:8443/sprintproject';
  submitForm(form: FormGroup) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>>  {
    
    let dataJson = JSON.stringify(form.value);
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "rejectUnauthorized": 'false',
    }),
    }
    
   
      const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${this.baseUrl}/adduser`, dataJson,httpOptions);
      return this.httpClient.request(req);
   
   
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClient cannot ignore or bypass self signed certificate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840830/httpclient-cannot-ignore-or-bypass-self-signed-certificate-error)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, your ssl certificate is invalid. You can skip ssl by using `http` instead of `https` but that would not be an actual fix.

Comment: when i use http, i got error certificate

Comment: after using http i got this error net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Obviously. Server is serving handshake on this port, you cannot just ignore ssl layer .